# Uploading 50Gb GIS data (csv files) contained in nested directories into PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, csv

I have two years worth of GIS data contained in CSV files stored in nested directories (per year, per month) so it looks like:

```
2013
   01
       2013-01-01.csv
       2013-01-02.csv
       etc.
   02
   etc.
2014
   01
       2014-01-01.csv
       2014-01-02.csv
       etc.
   02
   etc.
```

The files contain the fields: ID, timestamp, lat, long. Combined, it is around 50GB worth of data. I am looking for the most efficient way to load data stored in a folder hierarchy into a single table in PostGIS. (This is my 'training data', and I'll be working with 500GB later on.)

At the moment I am thinking about writing a PyQGIS script based on os.walk (still have to work out how, tips are very welcome) for loading all the points into QGIS, saving them into the same layer, and then loading that layer into PostGIS. But I can imagine this would not be most efficient.

Any suggestions for alternative routes?

Comment: how about a shell script and `ogr2ogr`?

Comment: Is `ID` unique across files, and do you care about it? That is, do you need or want a new primary key?

Comment: Shell script running psql `/COPY`, then crate `GEOMETRY` objects (and index) in a new column.

Comment: @LeeHachadoorian No this is the various vehicle IDs so it is not unique across files but I do care about it!

Answer (score 4):

You may choose:

- to use GDAL using `ogrmerge.py` like here but with setting a destination target not a file but your database compare to this example https://twitter.com/ThomasG77/status/1362118505819176966 See [ogrmerge doc](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrmerge.html)
- looping with bash doing something like below (not exact as it depends from your own table structure)

```bsh
psql -c "CREATE TABLE your_table_name (col1 text, col_x double precision, col_y double precision, geom geometry(Point, 4326));"

for i in */*/*.csv;
  do psql -c "COPY your_table_name(col1, col_x, col_y) FROM '"$i"' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"
done;
psql -c "UPDATE your_table_name SET geom = ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(col_x, col_y)) where geom is NULL;"
```

For docs, you can go to [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtable.html) and [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-copy.html)

You may also see how to change parameters when calling [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html) command line as contrary to my example, you will need to set the database name and connection related informations.

I've mentioned `COPY your_table_name(col1, col_x, col_y)` with explicit columns names as you may want to create a table with empty geometry column, populate the table and then update geometry column from columns content filled with the CSV `COPY`. You may prefer psql meta command [`\COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY)

For performances purpose, IMHO, it's not necessary to go through QGIS to load your CSVs.

Comment: Note that, while the server side *SQL* `COPY` may be a tad faster, the data needs to be accessible to the server instance, whose permissions are usually limited to the `PG_DATA` location on disk! *psql* has a client side [`/COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) meta command that is by far more versatile. The difference between using PGs native `COPY` protocol over `INSERT`s (or worse, proxy via QGIS) will be *several hours*...

Comment: Thanks for helping out @ThomasG77 ! I think I understand your approach, but I have never worked with bash/shell scripting. Does anyone know a good resource how to use it with GDAL/PostGIS?

Comment: Could I use Git Bash to run such a script?

Comment: You can, but if you are a windows user then powershell or a cmd window and batch file will work too (with a different less portable syntax)

Comment: Could someone comment the code above so I can better understand it? questions I have: since he just states 'in */*/*.csv', do I need to be in the folder where the nested directories are located? How would I loop through the directories as shown above? Is the i the rows in each csv file or one of the csv files itself. In this is example, are these assumptions correct > col1=ID, col_x=lat, col_y=long, timestamp=??. Why do I need a geometry column here, I don't have polygon data in the files. Sorry for the many questions, I am new to this..

Comment: For "in /*/.csv", it uses bash expansion to look for any CSV within any directories of any directories. I suppose you go from the root dir where your yearly dirs are. You don't need a geometry column except if after you want to make spatial queries in PostGIS and use spatial index to speed up queries like search me all points imported from my CSV files that are within a polygon you have in another PostGIS table. I imagined maybe wrongly that your CSV may contains X and y coordinates.